# Nginx: it takes too long to establish a ssl connection

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl

I have a nginx set up with ssl certifivate. Recently I noticed, that establishing connection to that server sometimes takes way too long (8+ seconds). In chrome developer tools I can see, that all of that time goes to connecting phase. Problem exists both for dynamic content (php) and for static (html, css). At the same time server responds flawlessly to the same, non-ssl requests. It does not happen for each request, but it causes timeouts to many of ajax requests (some of those are crucial to the service).

I tried to follow this guide: http://unhandledexpression.com/2013/01/25/5-easy-tips-to-accelerate-ssl/ but it didn't help.

Any idea how can I find the source of the problems? Any potential fixes?

Comment: So, when doing the actual request, the only request that takes a long time is the one directed to your server? One thing that could slow down the connection is the checking of certificate request status from your certificate provider. This will show up as a separate request from your browser to your certificate provider's OCSP URL.

Comment: You could also debug the slowness with debug_connection directive, which provides a very detailed log of request processing in nginx error log.

Comment: Run your server through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html and try to correct any problems it shows.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Yes, it seems, that the problem occurs only for my website. I did enable debugging, but all logs connected with that specific request comes from the same second (while connection phase took over 5s)

Comment: @Mxx I ran tool you provided, but there is only one issue according support for TLS 1.2. Everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: @Mxx Just to be clear, the single HTTP request showing up in HTTPFox / Network Console etc. takes many seconds, and there are no other HTTP requests around it? Of course other resources are loaded after that.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, usually there are other requests around and those are correct. Not only after, but before as well. It just happens that some random requests are taking much more time to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short, painful (yet correct) answer is:
It is not nginx-connected problem.

I did more testing via usage of wget loop and as it turns out it is not a server problem. Somehow connections from another location are correct. Yet it doesn't seem to be my connection problem because any other ssl on different server works correctly. 
Continuing to investigate further.